# How do I reduce CSV file size?

Tags: excel, powershell, csv

I have a PowerShell script that converts an .xlsx file (21.1MB) to a CSV file (16.5MB). When I open the .csv file that was created and press save, a dialog box pops up that says *"Some features in your workbook might be lost if you save it as a CSV. Do you want to keep using that format?"*, I press yes and the CSV file that was 16500KB shrinks to  58KB. I know that it must be deleting a lot of formatting in the file to do that, but I don't know how in PowerShell to replicate that reduction in file size. I have googled a lot but haven't found anything of use.

```
$files = Get-ChildItem C:\Users\user\Desktop\id.xlsx
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excel.Visible = $false
$Excel.DisplayAlerts = $false

foreach ($file in $files) {
    $WorkBook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($file.Fullname)
    $sheet = $workbook.Sheets.Item(1) # Activate the first worksheet
    [void]$sheet.Cells.Item(1, 1).EntireRow.Delete() # Delete the first row
    [void]$sheet.Cells.Item(1, 1).EntireColumn.Delete()      # Delete the first column

    #delete the next 31 rows
    for ($i=1;$i -le 32;$i++) {
        [void]$sheet.Cells.Item(1, 4).EntireColumn.Delete()
    }
    $NewFilePath = [System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($file.Fullname,".csv")
    $Workbook.SaveAs($NewFilepath, 6)   # CSV
}

# cleanup
$Excel.Quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($WorkBook) | Out-Null
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Excel) | Out-Null
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

Comment: Given that huge reduction in file size I would use a text editor to compare the output you produced compared to what happens when you open and save the file in Excel. Also I would note that every time you open a CSV file you will get that prompt on saving if you make any formatting changes as CSV never contains formatting.

Comment: The csv before and after contents remained the same. It's weird because the excel file I had PS convert only had 850 rows and 30 columns, 16mb seemed way to large for that to begin with.

Comment: Have you opened the CSV in a *text editor*. Don't double click it, open it in a text editor. I think your code is still saving an excel file with a different extension. It's still an excel file, not a CSV. A CSV file is a text file with no formatting that happens to open in Excel

Comment: When you comment _#delete the next 31 rows_ in the code, you are not deleting rows, but columns. `EntireColumn.Delete()` --> `EntireRow.Delete()`

Comment: @Theo the comment is wrong not the code :).

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I opened it in notepad and it reads exactly like it should. My current theory is that the other tabs that were in the original xlsx are still in the code, but are not dispalyed. I am going to add lines to my script to delete the other tabs and retry.

Comment: I recently saw similar and found excel was shortening the significant digits from -1.540879941689012E-001 to -1.54E-001.